Automatically integreate min/max/mean values from a table into the text
suppose I have the following table. Is it now possible to automatically determine values such as Min/Max/Mean from the respective columns and integrate them into a continuous text?
The text should then look something like this.

Column 2 shows the lower bound of model 1, with the minimum LB at ....
in iteration .... The mean lower bound is...

It should be determined as the minimum in column 2, and then also the corresponding instance. How does this work?
This is my code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 2}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5} 
Instance & LB & UB & LB & UB  \\
\midrule
1 & 343.7 & 1326.0 & 447.768 & 448.800 \\
2 & 0.0 & 1281.8 & 458.178 & 458.800 \\
3 & 323.1 & 1286.0 & 433.366 & 433.700 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Welcome! I suggest that you mention that you cross post, since it could waste people's time to write answers even if you already got something on the other site.

LaTeX can do anything, but if you want statistics in real-time, from data from your document, it is much simpler to make literate programming with a statistic language such as R. For this you need to have R with the knitr R package installed or use Overleaf. To use in Overleaf save it with the .Rtex extension. To compile locally, save it with the .Rnw extension and use Rstudio to compile it, or read the knitr documentation to make that from R directly.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,paperwidth=12cm,paperheight=7cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<data,echo=FALSE>>=
LB <- c(343.7,0.0,323)
@

Column 1 have values of \Sexpr{knitr::combine_words(LB)}, where the minimum  is \Sexpr{signif(min(LB),2)}, the maximum is \Sexpr{max(LB)}  and the mean value is \Sexpr{round(mean(LB),1)}\footnote{Well, really is \Sexpr{mean(LB)}  \ldots}

\bigskip\centering

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 2}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5} 
Instance & LB & UB & LB & UB  \\
\midrule
1 & \Sexpr{format(LB[1], nsmall = 1)} & 1326.0 & 447.768 & 448.800 \\
2 & \Sexpr{format(LB[2], nsmall = 1)} & 1281.8 & 458.178 & 458.800 \\
3 & \Sexpr{format(LB[3], nsmall = 1)} & 1286.0 & 433.366 & 433.700 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}

Edit:
If you want to use R in subdocuments, you must be aware that R calculus is a pre-processing step completely agnostic about the LaTeX markup, so in you want R included  in a  subdocument, you cannot use \input{} but say to  knitr where it should search, so, if you move the table "as is" to a file whatever.Rnw, you can insert it in the main file with:
<<mychildfile, child="whatever.Rnw">>=

@

(Disclaimer: Tested in Rstudio only, remember that In Overlead you will need another extension).
Said that, a simpler approach with subdocuments is use a Quarto markdown project is spite of the different syntax, because the first render step is simply merge all subdocuments, therefore the  export process is multiple .qmd → R → single .md → pandoc → single .tex → latex engine → single .pdf. So in this case you only have to be aware of put the subdocuments with R code in the right order.

Thank you for your answer. What do I have to modify, if let's say, I have the table and the data in table.Rtex and want to use the min's and max's in my main.tex, using overleaf? Sadly \input does work for ne

@mingabua The R part is a pre-processing step where first R make the computations of the file and the  code is replaced by an R output digestible for latex, the the file  is exported to a true latex version (.tex). The pdf output is exclusively a latex business in the last step, and  \input is done in this setp, so you are trying an impossible  dialog between R outputs or between some R code with some R output. But there others ways to deal with  R in subdocuments: if you want the simplest, this is probably Quarto.
